# ASP.Net MVC Attempt by method ... to access method 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(System.String, System.Object)' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I'm working on a project using ASP.Net MVC5, and getting MethodAccessException from within a controller method that tries to call System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(System.String, System.Object).

Here is the code snippet.

```
public class SectionBaseController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
  ...
}

public class SectionController<TModel> : SectionBaseController 
{
  ...
}

public class BookController<TModel> : SectionController<TModel>
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewBook(string autherName, List<TModel> viewModels)
    {
        // do some work
        var model = someResult;
        return View("BookView", model);
    }
}
```

BookView.cshtml is in Views/Book folder of the project.

When the application executes BookController.CreateNewBook method, System.MethodAccessException is thrown at line

```
return View("BookView", model);
```

The error message is:

> Attempt by method
>   'BookController 1.CreateNewBook(System.String,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1)' to access method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(System.String, System.Object)' failed.

As BookController indirectly inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Controller, I can't work out why it can't access View method which is defined as protected internal on System.Web.Mvc.Controller class.

There is a controller factory method which resolves the Controller instance from Unity container.

```
    public class ControllerFactory : System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return _unityContainer.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
    }
```

Have I missed anything?

Comment: How are you creating your controllers? Is it DI?

Comment: Do you use a custom controller factory and action invoker?

Comment: Yes, I used Unity container to resolve instance of Controller. I have updated in the post